# how to restructure the bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to restructure the carousal indicators to appear below the caption.
here is a fiddle of the carousel.

```
<pre>
    https://jsfiddle.net/w1jjeh7L/
</pre>
```

this is what i am trying to achieve
[image: here is what i am trying to achieve]

Comment: And what is your problem with that? Use your browser’s developer tools to find out what CSS rules are responsible for them being in the position they are normally in … and then overwrite those in your own CSS.

Comment: the indicators are not updating. I tried to push it to another div for indicators. https://jsfiddle.net/w1jjeh7L/

Comment: No idea what you mean by that. Everything in your fiddle seems to be working as is to be expected.

Comment: the carousel indicators should appear in a different div below the caption. They are appearing in the fiddle i just gave but they are not changing. as the carousel slides. i.e, the active class isnt updating. check this fiddle    
https://jsfiddle.net/w1jjeh7L/2/

Comment: Of course you can not just change the HTML structure that bootstrap imposes any way you like, and then expect that to still work … As I said, this should rather be done by changing the CSS formatting of those elements.

Comment: @CBroe sir thanks for the response. but maybe you didnt understand what i am trying to explain.  The looks can be modified by css i agree but i am looking for functionality

Answer (score 0):

Heres the fiddle updated. Managed to fix it right

```
updated fiddle:        https://jsfiddle.net/w1jjeh7L/3/
```